# unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'project' and 'int'

Tags: python, object, flask, orm, int

I have one column just ID, so I used this query to get the last record

```
 >>>obj = project.query.order_by(project.id.desc()).first()
```

Now I want to increment last record by one

```
>>>obj+1
```

I got this error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'project' and 'int'
```

btw,obj return this value:

```
<project 3>
```

how can return just 3 value as int?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
obj.ID+1 #ID of obj object+1,your are trying to add 1 with the project object
```